# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'ProgDB'

Tags: avr, atmega, avr-gcc

I get this error while compiling but I can not find the issue.

```
../DB.c:14: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'PatKarten'
```

Here is some code:

```
    const uint8_t PatKarten[29][16] PROGMEM =
    {
//  01  |  02  |  03  |  04  |  05  |   06  |  07  |  08  |  09  |  10  |  11  |  12  |  13  |   14  |  15  |  16  |  
                                                          //0xd3                                                
{   65  ,  66  ,   1  ,   2  ,   3  ,   4  ,   5  ,  6   , 0xdd ,   7  ,   0  ,   0  ,   0   ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 01  
{   65  ,  66  ,   7  ,   2  ,   3  ,   4  ,   5  ,  6   ,   1  , 0xd8 ,   0  ,   0  ,   0   ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 02
{   65  ,  66  ,   1  ,   8  ,   9  ,  10  ,  11  ,  12  , 0xd1 ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  ,   0   ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 03
{   65  ,  66  ,  13  ,  14  ,  15  ,  16  ,   9  ,  13  ,   14 ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  ,   0   ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 04
{   65  ,  66  ,   1  ,   7  ,   9  ,  17  ,  12  ,  18  ,   19 ,  17  ,  18  ,   0  ,   0   ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 05
{   65  ,  66  ,   1  ,  12  ,   9  ,  20  ,   1  ,  20  ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  ,   0   ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 06
{   65  ,  66  ,   1  ,  21  ,   7  ,  22  ,  21  ,   7  ,   8  ,  23  , 0xfc ,   7  ,  23   ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 07
{   65  ,  66  ,   1  ,  24  ,  20  ,  25  ,  22  ,  17  ,  23  ,  26  ,   5  ,  27  ,  21   ,  10  ,  25  ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 08    
{   65  ,  66  ,  25  ,  20  ,  21  ,  17  ,  28  ,  29  ,  30  ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  ,   0   ,   0  ,   0  ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 09 
{   31  ,  32  ,  33  ,  34  ,  35  , 0xc8 ,   0  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x0e0 , 0x00 , 0x00 ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 10
{   64  ,  36  ,  37  ,  38  ,  39  , 0xbc ,   0  ,   0  ,  69  ,  70  ,  71  ,  72  ,  73   ,  74  ,  75  ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 11
{   64  ,  40  ,  41  ,  42  ,  43  ,  44  ,  45  ,  46  ,  47  ,  48  ,  49  ,  50  ,  51   , 0xf4 ,   0  ,   0  },        // Karte Nr. 12 
{   64  ,  52  ,  53  ,  54  ,  55  ,  56  ,  57  ,  58  ,  59  ,  60  ,  61  ,  62  ,  63   , 0xfd , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 13  
{   64  ,  39  ,  46  ,  36  ,  48  ,  55  ,  61  ,  62  ,  33  ,  57  ,  38  ,  63  , 0x50  , 0xff , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 14
{  0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 15
{  0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 16
{    0  ,  33  ,  34  ,  35  ,  36  ,  37  ,  38  ,  39  ,  40  ,  41  ,  42  ,  43  ,  44   ,  45  , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 17
{    0  ,  48  ,  49  ,  50  ,  51  ,  53  ,  54  ,  55  ,  56  , 0xef , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 18
{    0  ,  69  ,  70  ,  71  ,  58  , 0xbf , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 19
{    0  ,   7  ,  21  ,  32  ,  42  ,  53  ,  60  , 0xef , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 20
{    0  ,  47  ,  48  ,  55  ,  57  ,  40  ,  55  , 0xef , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 21                
{    0  ,  65  ,  18  ,  49  ,  52  , 0xaa , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 22
{    0  ,   8  ,  32  ,  50  ,  54  , 0xbf , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 23
{    0  ,  57  ,  58  ,  15  ,  51  ,  56  ,  59  , 0xef , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 24
{  0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 25
{  0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 26
{  0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 27
{  0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 },        // Karte Nr. 28
{  0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00  , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 }     // Karte Nr. 29      

};
```

In other threads I only read that there is a missing semicolon, but I think I don't need any.

I am programming with AVRStudio 4, AVR-GCC 4.3.3 on an Atmega 8535.

Comment: I guess you did `#include  <stdint.h>` ... otherwise the real error can be (long) before line 14 ... look for missing `,;}`, but also for missing `#endif`

Comment: I did #include <stdint.h> in the main c-module. This code phrases is from another c-module and the lines I copied here are the first in this module were the error appears. I am new on Atmel programming and AVR studio. So I will take your advices and prove the code.

Comment: I built your code into one of my projects where I am using PROGMEM and it compiled OK (Studio 6.2 - AT90USB1287) ... my own declaration for a logarithmic dimming table for LEDs is `static const volatile uint8_t LOGTAB256[256] PROGMEM = {...}`

Comment: other question: why in the title you write "ProgDB" whereas the error message points to "PatKarten"? Is this significant/relevant?

Comment: You have to include `<stdint.h>` in every module that uses `uint8_t`. The code seems to stumble after `uint8_t`, so that may be your problem. But as @MikeD says, the error could be something else earlier that you are not showing in your question. The compiler tries to get as far as it can to allow for many possibilities of syntax and sometimes it gets very far before giving up.

Comment: There is the same error on ProgDB. So I think I copied the wrong message. @MikeD Which avr-gcc did you use?

Comment: Atmel Studio **6.2**, avr-gcc (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.4.5_1522) **4.8.1**

Comment: After I `#include <avr/pgmspace.h>` in this c-file the error disappears. But now I got some other errors. I do not know what forerunner did here -.-

Answer (score 0):

If your file extension is xxx.c try renaming it to xxx.cpp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).